# Sharing video and photo in metro apps through share charm

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

i am trying to take a picture and video from within the app and trying to share it through share charm but i am having a problem doing that. After i take the pic ,the share charm says it has trouble sharing the image. This is my code .Can anybody please let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
namespace Temp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Page1 : Page
    {

        private StorageFile _photo; // Photo file to share
        private StorageFile _video; // Video file to share





        private async void OnCapturePhoto(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
            var file = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

            if (file != null)
            {
                _photo = file;
                DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
            }
        }



        private async void OnCaptureVideo(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
            camera.VideoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat.Wmv;
            var file = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Video);

            if (file != null)
            {
                _video = file;
                DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
            }
        }

        void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            var request = args.Request;


            if (_photo != null)
            {
                request.Data.Properties.Description = "Component photo";
                var reference = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(_photo);
                request.Data.Properties.Thumbnail = reference;
                request.Data.SetBitmap(reference);
                _photo = null;

            }
            else if (_video != null)
            {
                request.Data.Properties.Description = "Component video";
                List<StorageFile> items = new List<StorageFile>();
                items.Add(_video);
                request.Data.SetStorageItems(items);
                _video = null;
            }

        }

      }


        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += OnDataRequested;

        }







}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your app to share, you must set the Title of the `DataPackagePropertySet` and at least one of the "SetXXX" methods. If you do not, you'll see the following message when trying to share "There was a problem with the data from ."

So add `request.Data.Properties.Title = "Title_of_photo_or_video";` in `OnDataRequested` event.

Comment: the app by default tries to share with skydrive. Anyway i can try to share it with email? Also what do you mean by SetXXX methods?Any example?

Comment: [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84) MSDN sample to share various files via share charm. SetXXX methods means, there's many methods for sharing different data like `SetData()`, `SetHtmlFormat()`, `SetText()`, etc